# Move remote file in SFTP using R and RCurl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I need to rename a remote file once I download them. I tried to use the following command, but its not working.

```
input = getURL(url, userpwd="user:password", postquote=c("/inputs/", "RNFR abc.xml", "RNTO abc.xml_processed"))
```

This is throwing the error message

`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Unknown SFTP command`

Please somebody suggest me some insight into this.

**Update**

I tried with the complete paths like,

```
input = getURL("url/abc.xml", userpwd="user:password", postquote=c("RNFR /inputs//abc.xml", "RNTO /inputs/abc.xml_processed"))
```

Still same error `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Unknown SFTP command`.

Comment: I think you can't have the directory as the first part of `postquote`. Can't you specify the filenames as paths (including the directory)?

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for your reply, I tried with the complete file paths, even then same error. I am not that familiar with Curl commands. Hope I am missing something.